# How can I remove unwanted piece of HTML markup on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have trouble with this piece of code. When I click it once, all is good and the behavior is as designed , but when I click it more than once, then there is all bunch of HTML that appears in the div (text area). How should I revise my JS  to make it not happen?

HTML :

```
<div id="transcriptText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
<br>
<div id="divideTranscript" class="button">&nbsp;Transform the Transcript!&nbsp;</div>
```

JS :

```
    window.onload = function() {

var transcriptText = document.getElementById("transcriptText");
var newTranscript = document.createElement("div");
var divideTranscript = document.getElementById("divideTranscript");
divideTranscript.onclick = EventHandler;

function EventHandler() {
    changeText();
}

function changeText() {
    var sArr = transcriptText.innerHTML.split(" ");
    transcriptText.innerHTML = "";
    console.log(sArr);
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
        var item = sArr[i];
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var newText = document.createTextNode(item);
        var dotNode = document.createTextNode(" ");

        newSpan.id = "word" + i;
        var mouseOverFunction = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        };
        newSpan.onmouseover = mouseOverFunction;

        var mouseOutFunction = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '';
        };
        newSpan.onmouseout = mouseOutFunction;
        newSpan.appendChild(newText);
        newSpan.appendChild(dotNode);
        transcriptText.appendChild(newSpan);
        count++;
    };
}
};
```

Here is it live http://jsfiddle.net/b94DG/1/

Comment: Is it a requirement of your solution to put it back into the same div with the same id, or could you remove that div and add another one with a different id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you use the `innerHTML` property instead of the `.textContent` property each time.

Here is an improved version of `changeText()` that doesn't matter how many times you run it:

```
function changeText() {
    var sArr = transcriptText.textContent.split(/\s+/g); // changed
    transcriptText.innerHTML = "";
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
        var item = sArr[i];
        if (!item) continue; // changed: don't add spans for empty strings
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        var newText = document.createTextNode(item);
        var dotNode = document.createTextNode(" ");

        newSpan.id = "word" + i;
        var mouseOverFunction = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; 
        };
        newSpan.onmouseover = mouseOverFunction;

        var mouseOutFunction = function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '';
        };
        newSpan.onmouseout = mouseOutFunction;
        newSpan.appendChild(newText);
        newSpan.appendChild(dotNode);
        transcriptText.appendChild(newSpan);
        count++;
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why using `.textContent` made a difference?